# Historical data on Credit default swap

Tags: bloomberg, cds

I am aware that there is an active `CDS` market for insurance from US sovereign default (in terms of treasury bond) as *Dimitri Vulis*
commented. I am looking for the historical data in time series on this `CDS` (premium).

I was trying to get historical `CDS` data from `Bloomberg` and found ticker `US CDS USD 5Y` as viewed below

[image]

However the quotes in here appears to be significantly different from http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/cds-historical-data/united-states/5-years/ (ref. comment from *Dimitri Vulis*) which provides a quote of 25.00.

Any explanation for such difference between `Bloomberg` and http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com? Am I looking at right ticker in `Bloomberg`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a market? yes https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2011-07-26/u-s-debt-default-swaps-invert-for-first-time-chart-of-the-day ; http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/cds-historical-data/united-states/5-years/ but what does it really mean? Should you be looking at USD- or EUR-denominated CDS?

Comment: You can just press F1F1 and ask the help desk for functionality and tickers.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I am looking for USD dominated.

Comment: Before using that for anything, you should look up this question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47359 and the references cited in my answer.

Comment: You are probably looking at the right place in Bloomberg but I can't say which series is more accurate. See the paper "[Are all credit default swap databases equal?](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w16590/w16590.pdf)" by Mayordomo et al (2010).